# Time rounding and columns combining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
'Customer_id': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3],
'order_time': ['2010-01-01 01:01:00', '2010-01-01 01:05:00' , '2010-01-01 01:24:00', '2010-01-01 01:27:00', '2010-01-01 01:33:00', '2010-01-01 01:34:00', '2010-01-01 01:35:00', '2010-01-01 01:37:00', '2010-01-01 01:38:00',  

'2010-01-13 05:52:00', '2010-01-13 05:53:00', '2010-01-13 05:54:00', '2010-01-13 05:58:00', '2010-01-13 06:04:00', '2010-01-13 06:14:00', '2010-01-13 06:25:00', '2010-01-13 06:024:00', '2010-01-13 06:26:00', '2010-01-13 06:27:00']})
```

I would like to round just the time regardless of the date.

The expected output:[image]

For Example:

1. For the date `2010-01-01 01:01:00` I would like to create a column `Round_10_min_start` that contains the rounded time: 01:00:00. And a column `Round_10_min_end` that contains the rounded time: `01:09:00` which means the scope of 10 minutes and that applies to all other users. So at the end I get for each row the created column `Round_combined` contains: `01:00:00-01:09:00` the scope 0f 10 minutes.
   Then create a new column `Freq_id` that contains the frequncy of each user in this period of time and another new column `Total` of all users that exist in that period of time. For instance, `id = 1` exists only one time in period `01:00:00-01:09:00` and the total of users in that period are 2.

Please have a look at the attached photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
df['Round_10_min_start'] = df['order_time'].dt.floor('10min')
df['Round_10_min_end'] = df['Round_10_min_start'] +  pd.Timedelta(minutes = 9)

df['Round_combined'] = df['Round_10_min_start'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S') + '-' + df['Round_10_min_end'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

df['Round_10_min_start'] = df['Round_10_min_start'].dt.time
df['Round_10_min_end'] = df['Round_10_min_end'].dt.time

df['Freq_id'] = df.groupby(['Customer_id', 'Round_combined'])['order_time'].transform('count')
df['Total'] = df.groupby(['Round_combined'])['Customer_id'].transform('count')
```

**Output**

```
    Customer_id order_time  Round_10_min_start  Round_10_min_end    Round_combined  Freq_id Total
0   1   2010-01-01 01:01:00 01:00:00    01:09:00    01:00:00-01:09:00   1   2
1   2   2010-01-01 01:05:00 01:00:00    01:09:00    01:00:00-01:09:00   1   2
2   1   2010-01-01 01:24:00 01:20:00    01:29:00    01:20:00-01:29:00   1   2
3   2   2010-01-01 01:27:00 01:20:00    01:29:00    01:20:00-01:29:00   1   2
4   1   2010-01-01 01:33:00 01:30:00    01:39:00    01:30:00-01:39:00   1   5
5   2   2010-01-01 01:34:00 01:30:00    01:39:00    01:30:00-01:39:00   1   5
6   3   2010-01-01 01:35:00 01:30:00    01:39:00    01:30:00-01:39:00   1   5
7   4   2010-01-01 01:37:00 01:30:00    01:39:00    01:30:00-01:39:00   2   5
8   4   2010-01-01 01:38:00 01:30:00    01:39:00    01:30:00-01:39:00   2   5
9   1   2010-01-13 05:52:00 05:50:00    05:59:00    05:50:00-05:59:00   2   4
10  2   2010-01-13 05:53:00 05:50:00    05:59:00    05:50:00-05:59:00   2   4
11  1   2010-01-13 05:54:00 05:50:00    05:59:00    05:50:00-05:59:00   2   4
12  2   2010-01-13 05:58:00 05:50:00    05:59:00    05:50:00-05:59:00   2   4
13  3   2010-01-13 06:04:00 06:00:00    06:09:00    06:00:00-06:09:00   1   1
14  4   2010-01-13 06:14:00 06:10:00    06:19:00    06:10:00-06:19:00   1   1
15  4   2010-01-13 06:25:00 06:20:00    06:29:00    06:20:00-06:29:00   1   4
16  2   2010-01-13 06:24:00 06:20:00    06:29:00    06:20:00-06:29:00   1   4
17  1   2010-01-13 06:26:00 06:20:00    06:29:00    06:20:00-06:29:00   1   4
18  3   2010-01-13 06:27:00 06:20:00    06:29:00    06:20:00-06:29:00   1   4
```